# How to save current date and time in flutter sqflie?

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, dart

I tried to save the current date and time in sqflite every time I save data into the db.

This is my date and time column

```
'last_fetched DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
```

and I tired this too

```
'last_fetched DATETIME CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
```

it is saving the date but not time.

**The result**

```
2021-05-15 07:06:52
```

**Where as the real time is**

```
2021-05-15 14:05:47
```

Comment: use localtime (with timezone), `timestamp DATE DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')),`

Comment: this didnt work, i tried.